# python outer loop to continue from inner loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

1I'm looping over a series of numbers looking for range of numbers (e.g. <100).

E.g.:
list = [1, 2, 3, 125, 7, 8, 9, 200].
I want to get in a file: 1-3, 7-9.
The problem I faced is that the outer loop will reiterate over items in an inner loop, so the output I get is: 1-3, 2-3, 3, 7-9, 8-9, 9.

My current strategy which works:

```
counter = 1

for i in range(len(list)):  # outer loop
    if counter > 1: # prevents the outer loop from iterating the numbers iterated in inner loop
        counter -= 1
        continue
    elif counter <=1:
        while list[i] < 100:
            i +=1
            counter +=1
            if list[i] > 100:
                print list[i-counter], '-', list[i]
                break
```

I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic way to get the outer loop to skip over items that have been iterated in the inner loop, instead of using an additional counter (like I did above). Thanks.

Edit: There have been few replies that focused on consecutive numbers. My mistake, the number don't have to be consecutive. I just need the first and last number in that range
E.g. list = [1,4,8, 12, 57, 200, 4,34, 300]. Output: 1 - 57, 4 - 34.
The list and criteria is dependent on user. The criteria will always be a number with comparison operator '<'. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need two loops. One is sufficient:

```
def ranges(seq):
  it = iter(seq)
  start = end = next(it)
  for val in it:
    if val == end + 1:
      end = val
    else:
      if end - start > 1:
        yield start, end
      start = end = next(it)

for start, end in ranges([1, 2, 3, 125, 7, 8, 9, 200]):
  print('%d-%d' % (start, end))
```

The logic is slightly different to yours: it looks for subsequences that consist of consecutive numbers (`1 2 3` and `7 8 9` in your example). If you need to, it's easy to change the logic to also break the sequences at any number `>= 100`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm still trying to figure it out. I've also added additional information on my problem, will your suggestion still work?

Comment: I tried this method and it works very well with what I need. A second question, I need the positions of the items as well in the list. Is there a quick way to get the index values of 'start' and 'end' as well? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

an alternative approach, based on while loops:

```
def print_ranges(given_list, limit):
    while given_list:
        start = end = given_list.pop(0)
        if start < limit:
            while given_list and (given_list[0] < limit):
                end = given_list.pop(0)
            if (end != start):
                print "%d-%d"%(start,end)  # or save it in another list
```

some tests:

```
>>> print_ranges([1,4,8, 200, 4,34, 72, 300], 100)
1-8
34-72

>>> print_ranges([1, 4, 8, 12, 57, 200, 4, 34, 300], 100)
1-57
4-34

>>> print_ranges([1, 4, 8, 12, 57, 200, 4, 34, 300], 250)
1-34
```

Comment: Sorry sorting is not an option. I failed to mention in my original post that the positions of the items in the list is important as well and will be outputted. Actually I'm not too clear whether your suggestion is in line with what I need. The criteria (e.g. <100) and list are actually dependent on user input.

Comment: ok, nevermind, it's really optional... I've added it for completeness and for future readers. :)

Comment: @jonoave I've edited my answer and added the constraint that end < 100. Obviously given_list will be provided by user input, I just defined it as in your question to provide a working example.

Comment: Thanks, your changes make a bit more sense now and I will try to see it fits with what I need.

Comment: @jonoave now it's more clear so I've changed the code a little bit to fit your second example. If you wish you can replace 100 with a variable (provided by the user)

Comment: Thanks, your edited code looks quite helpful now. But there are also other things to consider for my code and I'll see if I can modify your suggestion to fit mine. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the list will be used many times later in the script and constantly creating copies of it (cause pop() deletes entries from the list) is probably not very efficient.

Comment: If you use the proposed function you don't have to create duplicates. If you want to re-use the results you can save them into a list instead of printing them, that will work as a cache. If you need an example on how to do that I can edit my answer

Comment: I meant that given_list will be used for many other functions later in the script, not just with the one above for picking out a range of numbers (e.g. <100). Your pop() method means I have to create duplicate of given_list so that the original list can be used later.

Comment: I guess you are not using it inside the proposed function or you are trying to do other calculationd inside the outer while loop. If you want help on that please indicate in your code when you need access to the whole list inside the loop

Comment: The full script will be in blocks, and this is just one of the blocks. The given_list by the user will be used many times throughout the script, e.g. different criteria (<100, <500, even numbers, positions of the items). Your proposed method means that I have to create a duplicated copy of the given_list each time I want to use a similar function in a different block of code.

Answer (score 0):

using `zip()`:

`zip(lis,lis[1:])` returns something like:

```
 [(0, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 5),
 (5, 6),...]
```

now you can iterate over this list to check if the difference is 1 or not.

**code:**

```
In [103]: def ranges(lis):
    ans=[]
    z=zip(lis,lis[1:])
    for x,y in z:
        if y-x==1:
            ans.extend([x,y])
        else:    
            if ans:
                yield "{0}-{1}".format(min(ans),max(ans))
                ans=[]
    if ans:        
          yield "{0}-{1}".format(min(ans),max(ans))
   .....:         

In [104]: lis=[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,2,3,4]

In [105]: list(ranges(lis))
Out[105]: ['0-3', '5-8', '10-11', '2-4']
```